# Avoid index scan in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index

I need some help here please.

I'm currently troubleshooting some dynamic SQL which is taking an age to return the results. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, build 10.50.4305

I've carried out a SQL trace so I can now see what's going on and basically the culprit is a clustered index scan.

The select contains:

```
WHERE 
    Name LIKE @Query + '%' ESCAPE '\' 
ORDER BY
```

This causes a clustered index scan.

If I change the select to

```
WHERE 
    Name LIKE 'value' + '%' ESCAPE '\' 
ORDER BY
```

I get an index seek and a key lookup.

I've looked as using the forceseek query hint but I get the error....

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Any help or advice on how to keep the parameter in the query and to avoid the clustered index scan would be much appreciated.

### UPDATE (taken from comment by Shnugo)

> I've added the query to the original question and the value of @Query is the same everytime whether the result is fast or slow

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(50)

SET @Query = 'EIKO'

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT TOP 5 pex.Ric.Name AS Id, pex.Ric.Name + '|' + pex.Ric.DisplayName AS Name FROM pex.Ric WITH (nolock) WHERE pex.Ric.Name LIKE @Query + '%' ESCAPE '\' ORDER BY PeId, Name
```

Comment: Can you please post the table structure, any indexes defined on the table, and your full query?

Comment: if your name column has index ,i got seek in both the cases,plz provide test data for us to check the issue

Comment: A `LIKE` search with a `%` at the end should be able to use the index... Did you try to set your variable `@Query` to the same value, which works fast, (if placed as literal)? If your `@Query` contains other characters like the underscore or `[]` brackets (some more), which are used in `LIKE` patterns, this might trick you out... Provide some examples of the content of `@Query`

Comment: Addition: You speak about `dynamic SQL`... Very often in SQL you find underscores in object names (e.g. `object_id`) or brackets like `[dbo],[SomeTable]`. `LIKE` will try to use these as patterns...

Comment: If the statement really is dynamic SQL, couldn't it just be written better to only query exactly what you want to filter on, instead of calculating and concatenating in the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in my comments, I assume, that some characters sitting in your dynamic SQL are interpreted as pattern. The usage of `ESCAPE` can be a hint, that you are aware of this and you inserted replace characters to mark these special characters as *normal*...

It looks, as if you were just looking for the same beginning... Try this

```
WHERE LEFT(Name,LEN(@Query))=@Query
```

This should cut the same count of characters from the left side of `Name` and compare it with your `@Query` variable.

This approach will not be quite as fast, as it is not sargable and will not be able to use the index too, but - if my assumption is correct - it should be faster, than a `LIKE` which is doing complex pattern checks for each row...

### UPDATE (taken from comments below)

Could it be, that other heavy actions steal the server's ressources? Did you try without the `ORDER BY`?

I just tried it out and I can reproduce this. Searching for a literal means for the optimizer to know everything in advance: best prediction, best usage of statistics and index. Additionally your results could be misleading. If you execute this over and over, the results will be cached. With the identical query you might get very fast answers - but they are coming from the cache...

Parameter sniffing might be an issue too.

It could help to create the statement as string (with a literal) and use `EXEC` to run.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  This get's stranger.  Some times the query returns in 2 or 3 seconds and sometimes it returns in minutes.  Everytime the Execution plan is the same whether the result is fast or slow.  It's a clustered index scan everytime.  How can I understand what's going on?

Comment: @user2841861 Please provide more details, especially the content of `@Query` for a fast and for a slow run.

Comment: I've added the query to the original question and the value of @Query is the same everytime whether the result is fast or slow.

Comment: @user2841861, Could it be, that other heavy actions steal the server's ressources? Did you try without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: removing the order by means the query runs quickly every time.  There's still a clustered index scan but the execution plan only has 4 items as opposed to 6 items with the order by

Comment: @user2841861 I just tried it out and I can reproduce this. Searching for a literal means for the optimizer to know everything in advance: best prediction, best usage of statistics and index. Additionally your results could be misleading. If you execute this over and over, the results will be cached. With the identical query you might get very fast answers - but they are coming from the cache... *Parameter sniffing* might be an issue too. It could help to create the statement as string (with a literal) and use `EXEC` to run.

Comment: thanks so much.  I'm going to move the db to another disk as I've confirmed the disk is the busiest out of all of them.  I'll also take your suggestion on board.  Without doubt searching the literal is fast every single time.

Comment: @user2841861 Thx, I'm glad to read this. Just edited my answer with the comments content to justify your acceptance :-D